# Trying to migrate a sample .Net FX4.8 console app to package reference and getting error

Tags: c#

Given:
Nuget Package:  Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
Visual Studio 2019 Console App .Net Framework 4.8

https://github.com/rodsantest1/SpatialDataSetupSol

The preceding project is prior to migrating to package references from package.config
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/

I'm getting an error when I do the migration as shown in image below. After migration `SqlServerTypes` doesn't exist in the current context where it did before.

What do I have to do to migrate it to package reference in this very minimal setup?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to mix old non-sdk style project with `PackageReference`? I don't think this is a good idea. But you can convert the project to sdk-style and then use `PackageReference` and it should work as expected. And note that you can still target `net48` with the sdk-style project.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by non-sdk style project vs sdk style

Comment: Non-sdk is an old-style project format like you have for now (`csproj` starting with `<Project ToolsVersion...`. Sdk-style is a new (from the net core beginning, I guess) human-readable and editable format, starting with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` (or other skd name). See here for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#project-files

Comment: @Serg this got me in the correct direction, thank you. If you want to add preceding to answer I'll gladly mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you are trying to use `<PackageReferece/>` in the old non-sdk-style project. I'm not sure if this shold work by design or not, but from my experience such a mix can lead to strange behaviour.

So, I can suggest to convert the project to the sdk-style (this includes moving package list inside the `csproj`) and this should work as expected. Read more about sdk-style projects here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#project-files.

You can also use Upgrade Assistant to convert your projects. Read more at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant. You may need to adjust your project after upgrade assistant, at least revert target framework to `net48`.